# Expand content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html menu. The markdown must remain as shown. Need to expand content on ""-link hover

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div-in row-menu" data-menu-block="first-div-in">Title</div>
      ..some other buttons..
</div>
<div id="first-div-in" class="menu-in">
  <div class="container" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      ... here is content ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is in realization. The idea is that when the user hovers on "div"-link, it expands the container with content. When the user changes the mouse position to this container, the container must be still visible.

The JS:

```
var hover_menu = function() {
  var parent = $(this);
  var menu_block = $( parent ).data('menu-block');
  $('#' + menu_block).slideToggle('slow');
}
$('.row-menu').on( 'hover', hover_menu );
```

My JS code must expand container on "div"-link hover. The container must be visible on changing the cursor position to expanded container. How can I realize this kind of behavior?

Comment: Have you tried using `onmouseover`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. On mouseover, if the current item is already visible then do nothing. Otherwise, hide any other open sections and show the new one.

```
var hover_menu = function(){
    var $parent = $(this);
    var $menu_block = $('#' + $parent.data('menu-block'));


    if ($menu_block.not(':visible')) {
       $('.menu-in:visible').not($menu_block).slideOut('slow');
       $menu_block.slideIn('slow');
    }
}
$('.row-menu').on( 'mouseover', hover_menu );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could do this menu with simple css, using max-height and overflow(hidden).

```
<div class="menu-container">
<div class="visible-content">
  My menu
</div>
<div class="invisible-content">
 <div class="content-of-invisible-div">
 <ul>
 <li>My first item</li>
 <li>My second item</li>
 <li>My third item</li>
 </ul>
 </div>

</div>
```

```
.menu-container:hover .invisible-content {
   max-height: 100px
}
.invisible-content{
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.visible-content{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content-of-invisible-div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here's the fiddle

[ttps://jsfiddle.net/7w1rts24/](https://jsfiddle.net/7w1rts24/)